# delete message for one user but not for the other

Tags: mysql

hello I have a database with 3 tables.

```
USERS('user_id','name','surname') 
MESSAGE_GROUP('user_one','user_two', 'hash')
MESSAGES('from_id','group_hash', 'messages')
```

My php code enables me to send messages between users. My question is how to enable a user to delete a message from its mailbox but the other user still watching the message. The messages must be full deleted only if both users delete the message. I am not interesting about the code, I am interesting only in finding the logic behind this. Any proposals that includes mysql code are welcome. thanks

Comment: Go through my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085067/delete-message-for-one-user-but-not-for-the-other/17085238#17085238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow this. :)

1. You can keep an extra field in `message_group` table something like `'deleted_from'` which will be initially `0`
2. If user one deletes it make the value of `'deleted_from'=1`, if user two deletes it, make the value of `'deleted_from' = 2.`
3. When you go to delete the message for a user, and you find the value `'deleted_from'` other than 0, delete the message completely, else mark the value of `'deleted_from'` as `'1'` or `'2'`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either:

1. Make a new table that specifies the mailboxes the message resides in, so that you can connect it to both users mailboxes
2. Or duplicate the message so that each user has their own copy that can be deleted
3. Add flags to the message table (not recommended) indicating whether the sender or recipient has deleted it. This I would avoid as it will not scale well if you have (or intend to add) group messaging.

Answer (score 0):

add to MESSAGE_GROUP a status field with values :

0 no owner and should be deleted
1 only the sender owns the message
2 only the reciever owns the message
3 both sender and recievers own it

Answer (score 0):

I would change the fields from the table in between like this (example that every user only can send a message to one person at a time):

```
    USERS('user_id','name','surname') 
    MESSAGE_GROUP('user_id','message_id')
    MESSAGES('from_id', 'to_id', 'messages')
```

So every user that has a message, will have a row in the MESSAGE_GROUP. When one user deletes the post, delete that row in MESSAGE_GROUP